# Rounding off to nearest number

Tags: text-processing, awk, floating-point

I have a file with data like this

```
vserver-1 vserver-1_root 0.95 0.0019043 0.948047
vserver-1 home  10.00 8.25 1.75
vserver-1 usr 95 45.65 39.35
vserver-1 file0 100 89.15 10.85
```

Desired formatted output with `awk`(rounding off to nearest whole number)

```
vserver-1 vserver-1_root 1 0 1
vserver-1 home  10 8 2
vserver-1 usr 95 46 39
vserver-1 file0 100 89 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `%0.f` is simplest way to convert float value to nearest whole number:

```
awk '{printf ("%s %s %.0f %.0f %.0f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5)}' file
```

Comment: Also note the comments about floating point rounding in e.g. [GNU awk's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html). For example, on my machine both `1.5` and `2.5` round to `2`, since the FP system rounds halves to the nearest even number, not up. This may or may not be what one wants.

Comment: How do I print comma between the values using printf?

Comment: comma between only values, or replace all spaces with a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have fixed 5 columns file, then you would do:

```
awk '{printf("%s %s %d %d %d\n",$1, $2, $3+.5, $4+.5, $5+.5)}' infile
```

This adds **0.5** to the fields then `%d` will remove the fractional part, resulting in the usual rounding to the nearest integer, with halves (e.g. 2.5) rounded up.

Comment: Here, too, `printf("%d", x - .5)` doesn't round `x` down correctly: `%d` _truncates_, so if `x=1.3`, `x-.5=.8`, then the truncated value is `0`.

Comment: as a floor function, it was broken. `1.3` should floor to `1`, not to `0`. Again, the point is that the float to int conversion done by `%d` _truncates_, i.e. lops off the whole fractional part. It doesn't do any rounding, that's why you need the `+ 0.5` to begin with. If you want to round towards zero to the nearest integer, it's enough to just use `printf("%d", x)`

Comment: Yes, my bad. you are right

Answer (score 0):

to round up , use +0.5 and print via `%d`

```
echo "$number" | awk '{ printf("%d", $1 + 0.5) }'
```

For your given string ,

```
vserver-1 vserver-1_root 0.95 0.0019043 0.948047 vserver-1 home 10.00 8.25 1.75 vserver-1 usr 95 45.65 39.35 vserver-1 file0 100 89.15 10.85
```

use this command :

```
awk '{printf "%s %s %d %d %d %s %s %d %d %d %s %s %d %d %d %s %s %d %d %d\n" , $1, $2, $3+0.5, $4+0.5, $5+0.5, $6, $7, $8+0.5, $9+0.5, $10+0.5, $11, $12, $13+0.5, $14+0.5, $15+0.5, $16, $17, $18+0.5, $19+0.5, $20+0.5}' filename
```

Comment: looking at the [markdown source of the original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/e35822a6-8608-4a23-aa01-7f0603072a59/view-source), I think they meant the input data was split on lines, five fields each

Comment: Also, you can't round down with `printf("%d", x - 0.5)`. If `x` is say, `1.3`, then `x - 0.5 = 0.8`, which is truncated to `0`. And with `+ 0.5` you don't get rounding up, but the usual rounding to nearest with `.5` going up.

Comment: yeah you are right, this hack works only for going up